# Print out memory content for base and inherited class

Tags: c++, c++03

I am trying to add a print() member function that would output memory content of an object, as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A {
 public:
    virtual std::string print() {
        std::string s;
        s.append(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this), 0, sizeof(A));
        return s;
    }
};

class B : public A {
 public:
    B() : a('a') {}
    char a;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    std::cout << "A \"" << a.print() << "\"\n";
    std::cout << "B \"" << b.print() << "\"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

How can I print the entire length of B, the listing above prints only the A portion of the class B.

Comment: You need a non virtual function of that calls th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a templated base with non-virtual function.

```
template<class T> class PrintMe
{
    public:

         std::string print() const
         {
               std::string s;
               s.append(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this), 0, sizeof(T));
               return s;
         };
};

class A: public PrintMe<A>
{
     // whatever
};

class B: public PrintMe<B>
{

};

//   and in code which uses it

std::cout << some_b.print();
```

Essentially the rule is that any class, `X`, which needs ability to print itself inherits from `PrintMe<X>`.

Personally, I wouldn't use inheritance or do this as a member function of the class at all, instead doing

```
template<class T> std::string print(const T &x)
{
    std::string s;
    s.append(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x), 0, sizeof(x));
    return s;
}

// and in some code which needs this

std::cout << print(some_b);

//  or, more explicitly

 std::cout << print<B>(some_b);
```

Note that this avoids virtual function dispatch completely, instead relying on the type of the object being identified at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

To do this safely, you'd have to override the virtual function for B:

```
std::string print() override {
    std::string s;
    s.append(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this), 0, sizeof(B));
    return s;
}
```

Why ?  Because you can't be sure that A and B have the same address (for instance if there would be [multiple base classes](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/multiple-inheritance-considered-useful/184402074)).

If you're fond of such dumping function,  in order to reduce code, you could use a template and invoke the template in each override.

Comment: Yes, I do know of this, but I wanted something that is set and forgot...

Answer (score 0):

> How can I print the entire length of B...

You might consider 'chaining' your print methods within the class hierarchy.

Your plan fails to handle non-printable values. I don't see a 'hex' conversion either.  But, presuming your cast to char* does what you want ...

```
class A {
public:
   virtual std::string print() {
       std::string s;
       s.append(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this), 0, sizeof(A));
       return s;
   }
};

class B : public A {
public:
   B() : a('a') {}
   char a;

   virtual std::string print() {
       std::string s = A::print(); // get A contents
       s.append(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this), 0, sizeof(B));
       return s;
   }
};
```

Not tested.

Also, these issue are implementation dependent.

It has been my experience (almost entirely with g++) that an instance of B contains all the data of both A and B (and I think A is in front i.e. lower address).  An instance of A has only data of A, and can not tell, does not know anything about any derived classes.

If in your implementation, B has all of A and B data (easy to tell, just print the sizeof(A) and sizeof(B) and compare to expectations.), you need not invoke A::print() inside of B::print().

Also note - if either class uses containers, the container data you wish to print is likely not in the stack space of your class instance.  Containers (vector, heap, list, etc.) use heap.  So you would find pointers on the stack, and the data elsewhere.

update --

Here is a small attempt to reveal parts of the g++ implementation details.

My interpretation is that it shows that a class B instance contains the data attributes of a class A instance in front (at a lower address) of the class B data attributes.  And that B is twice the size of A.

For this code I removed the virtual keywords.  Virtual affects the size of these objects in the way I expected it to.  But without keyword, the size is exactly what I expect for the uint64_t .. 8 (in A) and 16 (in B) bytes.

```
  class A
  {
  public:
     A() :
        aData(0x3132333435363738)
        {
        }

     ~A(){ }

     std::string dump()
        {
           std::stringstream ss;
           ss << "     this: " << &(*this);
           ss << "    aData: " << &aData << std::endl;
           return(ss.str());
        }

     std::string show()
        {
           std::stringstream ss;
           ss << std::hex << "0X" << aData << std::endl;
           return ss.str();
        }

     uint64_t aData; // 8 bytes
  };


  class B : public A
  {
  public:
     B() : bData(0x3837363534333231)
        {
        }

     ~B(){ }

     uint64_t bData;  // 8 bytes

     std::string dump()
        {
           std::stringstream ss;
           ss << "     this: " << &(*this);
           ss << " A::aData: " << &(A::aData) << "  bData:" << &bData 
              <<  std::endl; 
           return(ss.str());
        }

     std::string show()
        {
           std::stringstream ss;
           ss << std::hex << "0x" << A::aData << "  0x" << bData 
           << std::endl;
           return ss.str();
        }

  };

  int t405(void)
  {
     A a;
     B b;

     std::cout << "\nsizeof(a): " << sizeof(a) << std::endl;
     std::cout <<   "sizeof(b): " << sizeof(b) << std::endl;

     std::cout << "\ninstance a: " << &a << std::endl;
     std::cout <<   "instance b: " << &b << std::endl;

     std::cout << "\ninstance a - aData: "  << a.dump() << std::flush;
     std::cout << "\ninstance b - bData: "  << b.dump() << std::flush;

     std::cout << "\ninstance a show(): " << a.show() << std::flush;

     std::cout << "\ninstance b show(): " << b.show() << std::flush;

     return(0);
  }
```

The output should look something like this:

```
sizeof(a): 8 sizeof(b): 16

instance a: 0x7ffe73f5b5d0 instance b: 0x7ffe73f5b5e0

instance a - aData:      this: 0x7ffe73f5b5d0    aData: 0x7ffe73f5b5d0

instance b - bData:      this: 0x7ffe73f5b5e0 A::aData: 0x7ffe73f5b5e0  bData:0x7ffe73f5b5e8

instance a show(): 0X3132333435363738

instance b show(): 0x3132333435363738  0x3837363534333231
```

Answer (score -1):

First, you can
`#include <stdint.h>`

now you're able to cast your object to uint8_t, and iterating it by for-loop, (size = sizeof(object)).

Printing its hex value to stdin by printf:

```
printf("%hu", val[i]);
```

Comment: `std::uint8_t` is at best a typedef for the real 'byte representation' type `[un/signed] char` and at worst a different type that doesn't have the same special privileges as the `char` family. Just use `unsigned char`.